# What is the correct way of getting the start and end date of a ISO week number in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, iso, datetime

I have the ISO week and year but how do I correctly convert that into two dates representing the start and end of that week?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of strategies to do that:

- [Start of week function](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=47307)
- [End of week function](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=64760)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got some SQL chops, you could prune relevant bits from [F_TABLE_DATE](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519). Or, if you like having a monster function around, you could just use the whole shebang. You'd have to manufacture a sensible start and end date to pass into F_TABLE_DATE though.